# Changing the layout of an activity through pending intent

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, background, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to change the colour of the same activity that sends the notification through the use of a pending intent. My idea of how it works is the following:

1) AuthenticationMode class sends a notification with a pendingIntent that contains an integer extra

2) Notification gets sent, the user clicks on it and then goes back into the same activity

3) onNewIntent is called, gets the extra integer and based on the value gotten from the extra in the intent, changes the colour of the layout to "#00FF00" if 1 or "#f35336" if 0.

To my understanding, this is correctly being executed but for some reason, the background colour still does not change.

**It works when I make use of the method authenticate (onclick: authenticate) to call colorChanger(int result), but when making use of the notification/pending intent, it enters color changer and logcat prints: Log.d("colorchanger","result 1 entered if loop and past color changer");, but even then it doesn't work**

Here I provide more information about the problem:

```
public class AuthenticationMode extends Activity {

    //For device enabled lockscreen
    private DevicePolicyManager mgr = null;
    private ComponentName cn= null;

    //For Notification
    private final String CHANNEL_ID = "authenticate";
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 002;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    private ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    private Button mAuthenticationButton;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    //Temporary variable
    private int authenticationcounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication_mode);
        initializeViews();

        // battery power setting
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "sensors_data_logger:wakelocktag");
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        cn = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
        mgr = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {

        mAuthenticationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_authenticate);
        mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.authentication_layout);

    }

    public void authenticate(View view){
        if(mgr.isAdminActive(cn)) {
            mgr.lockNow();
            displayNotification(1);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    getString(R.string.permission_explanation));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    private void displayNotification(int result){
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent authenticationIntent = new Intent(this, AuthenticationMode.class);
        Log.d("Passedresult", "result = " + result);
        authenticationIntent.putExtra("authentication result", result);
        authenticationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent authenticationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, UUID.randomUUID().hashCode(), authenticationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Hi, phone owner");
        builder.setContentText("Click me to authenticate");
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(authenticationPendingIntent);


        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            CharSequence name = "Stop Notification";
            String description = "Stops the data recording";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name,importance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d("ONNEWINTENT", "onNewIntent is called");
        setIntent(intent);
        processIntent();

    }

    private void processIntent(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.d("processIntent", "processIntent called");
        if(intent!=null){
            Log.d("nonnull", "non null intent");
            int result = intent.getIntExtra("authentication result", 2);
            Log.d("gotextra","Got result: " + result);
            if (result == 1){
                Log.d("ifloop","result 1 entered if loop");
                colorChanger(result);
                authenticationcounter += 1;
            } else if (result == 0){
                Log.d("ifloop","result 0 entered if loop");
                colorChanger(result);
                authenticationcounter +=1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void colorChanger(int result){
        if (result == 1){
            mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            Log.d("colorchanger","result 1 entered if loop and past color changer");
            authenticationcounter += 1;
        } else if (result == 0){
            mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f35336"));
            authenticationcounter +=1;
        }
    }


}
```

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AuthenticationMode"
    android:id="@+id/authentication_layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/authenticationTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/authenticateLabel"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_authenticate"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
        android:onClick="authenticate"
        android:text="@string/start_title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#3D5AFE"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am aware that: **displayNotification(1);** I am passing a static value, but I was doing that for testing. Even then, the colour doesn't change to: "#00FF00"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void colorChanger(int result){
            if (result == 1){
                mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOne));
                Log.d("colorchanger","result 1 entered if loop and past color changer");
                authenticationcounter += 1;
            } else if (result == 0){
                mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTwo));
                authenticationcounter +=1;
            }
        }
```

Add these two color in your color.xml file. Like below

```
    <color name="colorOne">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="colorTwo">#f35336</color>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately it didn't work. Also, getResources().getColor(color) is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry as I can see this is not deprecated. What version is that showing it is deprecated?